# RabbitMQ - Removed unacked messages on a queue that does not have any consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message

We have a backup queue in RabbitMQ that simply keeps a copy of old messages for human consumption. There are no consumers on this queue, and the only way to view messages is to use the Get Messages UI/API.

The issue is that one of the users tried to Get over 24k messages with requeue enabled, and the queue got into a bad state.

Currently I see that there are 24k *unacked* messages, but I don't have any consumers on the queue.

All I want to do at this point is purge the queue to get rid of the old messages, but I cannot clear the ones that are unacked. And since there are no consumers, I am not aware of any connection that I can close which would move the messages back into ready status.

Is there any Admin action I can do to empty out the contents of this queue?
If not, is there anything I can do at this point to move the message back into ready status?

**Edit:** Other similar questions on this topic all have consumers whereas I do not, so their solutions don't apply to me. Hence why I am creating this as a new question.

Thank you

[RabbitMQ Screenshot of Unacked Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdNcI.png)

Comment: As a clarification- all of these unacked messages wound up there by virtue of being delivered to the web client?

Comment: Also, in general, this is not a valid use-case for RabbitMQ. If you want to look at messages, drain this queue by saving them off to a database, which can then be navigated at will.

Comment: Hi @theMayer, yes, that is correct all we have two queue (call them q1 and q1bkp). We send the same messages to both, but q1 has a consumer that takes the messages and acts on them, and q1bkp has no consumer so a person can manually review the data.

Your point about a DB is correct, thank you. We just don't have this because we are developing some software for a client and needed a quick-n-dirty way to check our integration messages without spending billable hours to stand up a DB based tool.

Comment: We have had the same problem on RabbitMQ 3.8.9, and have used the same resolution (delete/recreate the queue). Fortunately the messages were not very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any Admin action I can do to empty out the contents of this queue?

Yes. Simply delete and re-declare the queue. There should be a button in the management console that does this for you, then you'd have to re-declare it manually as well as re-bind it to the exchange. If you're worried about losing other messages, you can declare a new queue with a different name before deleting the old one.

> And since there are no consumers, I am not aware of any connection that I can close which would move the messages back into ready status.

This is a tough one. The management command to get messages is supposed to immediately "nack" the message to put it back in the queue (depending on settings). This is probably a bug, but the use-case that you describe (just having a queue that accumulates messages with no consumer) is not really a valid use case, so even if it is a bug, it may not be a huge priority for someone to work.

**Note** that unacked messages are tied to a particular *channel* and not a specific consumer (I assume, but do not know for a fact, that the management API works by creating a channel under the hood). So it also might be possible to requeue these by shutting down and restarting the management plug-in, or even possibly the broker (though all bets are off there).

From [this post](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2014-February/033513.html), the following should restart the management plugin:

`rabbitmqctl eval 'application:stop(rabbitmq_management).'
rabbitmqctl eval 'application:start(rabbitmq_management).'`

Comment: Thank you, @theMayer! That's exactly what I needed to know. I will try to delete and recreate the queue the way you suggested.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it some more, shutting down the management plugin sounds like a good option to try before deleting the queue. My one reservation is that I have not tried to do this while our application was still running: Are you aware if shutting down the management plugin would impact the delivery or consumption of messages? -- Again thanks for your spot on answer. This was exactly what I was trying to find out.